# how to correctly remove element in gwt (both `DOM.isOrHasChild` & `DOM.removeChild` were deprecated)?

Tags: gwt

Ok, this code works

```
if(DOM.isOrHasChild(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), DOM.getElementById("loading"))){
        DOM.removeChild(RootPanel.getBodyElement(), DOM.getElementById("loading"));
}
```

However, both `DOM.isOrHasChild` & `DOM.removeChild` were deprecated. Then, the question is:

What are the undeprecated code that can do the same task as the bove code? maybe use `releaseCapture` or something likes that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Classes [Document](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html) and [Element](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Element.html) have the needed methods:

```
Element body = Document.get().getBody();
Element loading = Document.get().getElementById("loading");

if(body.isOrHasChild(loading)){
    loading.removeFromParent();
}
```